# How to increase user life in a game at background service, even if the app is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, background-service

I want to increase user life with periodic time in a game, even if the app is destroyed. For instance, increase user life every 15 minutes even if the app is killed. I saw so many games use this method like below image.

increase_user_life

[image]

What is the best way to doing this ?

I tried CountdownTimer and Service methods, but if the app is destroyed, service stops. Also BroadcastReceiver has limitations above Android 8.0(Oreo). How can I reach this purpose in Android Studio (Java)?

Comment: Why does this need to be in the background rather than calculated when the app is restarted?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is an another way, but some users to move their phone's clock forward. So, this cause may wrong calculation. Thanks for advice.

Comment: If you want to stop users from cheating, then you must introduce a server where all the calculations happen

Comment: Yes, probably I should follow your advice. The best way seems yours advice. Thanks both of you.